# Android: Native Video Player events

Tags: android, video-player

When using native video player to play the video,

**Is it possible to know whether the user has seen the entire video** ((i.e) functionality somewhat similar to VideoView's onCompleteListener) or **exited the Video somewhere in the middle?**

I know I can use the VideoView to achieve this scenario but I don't want to use the default media controller and also I want to keep designing the media controller from scratch as the Last option...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: could you be more elaborate about your situation. are you using mediaplayer or videoview. i guess mediaplayer does have onCompleteListner as well.

Answer (score 2):

use startActivityForResult, and check if there is something in the returned Intent. Also, the notion of "native player" implies that the player might be different from a device to another. Which in turn implies that you may have different info depending on the device your app runs on.

Comment: @njzk2... Thank you for your answer. The intent provided by startActivityForResult contains no values and the resultCode is always zero. What I wanted to know was is there any property that we can use to determine the playback time?